# Is there any need of log table

Tags: mysql

I am developing an application that has database of mysql having orders and orderdetails table. order table having column orderStatus. My question is whether it is necessary to create another order log table if order status is 'closed' (that means completed orders) or just orderstatus column is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you have described, I would assume a column is sufficient.

You might need another table if:

- An order can have more than one status at the same time
- You need to keep a history of when the order changed status

There might be other cases that would require another table, but you haven't described that any such condition applies in your case, as far as I can tell.